# Access model instance inside model field

Tags: python, django, class, django-models, instance

I have a model (Event) that has a ForeignKey to the User model (the owner of the Event).
This User can invite other Users, using the following ManyToManyField:

```
    invites = models.ManyToManyField(
                  User, related_name="invited_users", 
                  verbose_name=_("Invited Users"), blank=True
              )
```

This invite field generates a simple table, containing the ID, event_id and user_id.

In case the Event owner deletes his profile, I don't want the Event to be deleted, but instead to pass the ownership to the first user that was invited.

So I came up with this function:

```
    def get_new_owner():
        try:
            invited_users = Event.objects.get(id=id).invites.order_by("-id").filter(is_active=True)
            if invited_users.exists():
                return invited_users.first()
            else:
                Event.objects.get(id=id).delete()
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass
```

This finds the Event instance, and returns the active invited users ordered by the Invite table ID, so I can get the first item of this queryset, which corresponds to the first user invited.

In order to run the function when a User gets deleted, I used on_delete=models.SET:

```
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='evemt_owner', verbose_name=_("Owner"), on_delete=models.SET(get_new_owner()))
```

Then I ran into some problems:

1. It can't access the ID of the field I'm passing
2. I could'n find a way to use it as a classmethod or something, so I had to put the function above the model. Obviously this meant that it could no longer access the class below it, so I tried to pass the Event model as a parameter of the function, but could not make it work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First we can define a strategy for the `Owner` field that will call the function with the object that has been updated. We can define such deletion, for example in the `<i.app_name/deletion.py` file:

```
# app_name/deletion.py

def SET_WITH(value):
    if callable(value):
        def set_with_delete(collector, field, sub_objs, using):
            for obj in sub_objs:
                collector.add_field_update(field, value(obj), [obj])
    else:
        def set_with_delete(collector, field, sub_objs, using):
            collector.add_field_update(field, value, sub_objs)
    set_with_delete.deconstruct = lambda: ('app_name.SET_WITH', (value,), {})
    return set_with_delete
```

You should pass a *callable* to `SET`, not call the function, so you implement this as:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models import Q
from app_name.deletion import SET_WITH

def get_new_owner(event):
    invited_users = event.invites.order_by(
        'eventinvites__id'
    ).filter(~Q(pk=event.owner_id), is_active=True).first()
    if invited_users is not None:
        return invited_users
    else:
        event.delete()


class Event(models.Model):
    # …
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='owned_events',
        verbose_name=_('Owner'),
        on_delete=models.SET_WITH(get_new_owner)
    )
```

Here we thus will look at the invites to find a user to transfer the object to. Perhaps you need to exclude the current `.owner` of the event in your `get_new_owner` from the collection of `.inivites`.

We can, as [@AbdulAzizBarkat says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69207710/access-model-instance-inside-model-field/69207958?noredirect=1#comment122322044_69207958), better work with a CASCADE than explicitly delete the `Event` object , since that will avoid infinite recursion where an `User` delete triggers an `Event` delete that might trigger a `User` delete: at the moment this is not possible, but later if extra logic is implemented one might end up in such case. In that case we can work with:

```
from django.db.models import CASCADE

def SET_WITH(value):
    if callable(value):
        def set_with_delete(collector, field, sub_objs, using):
            for obj in sub_objs:
                val = value(obj)
                if val is None:
                    CASCADE(collector, field, [obj], using)
                else:
                    collector.add_field_update(field, val, [obj])
    else:
        def set_with_delete(collector, field, sub_objs, using):
            collector.add_field_update(field, value, sub_objs)
    set_with_delete.deconstruct = lambda: ('app_name.SET_WITH', (value,), {})
    return set_with_delete
```

and rewrite the `get_new_owner` to:

```
def get_new_owner(event):
    invited_users = event.invites.order_by(
        'eventinvites__id'
    ).filter(~Q(pk=event.owner_id), is_active=True).first()
    if invited_users is not None:
        return invited_users
    else:  # strictly speaking not necessary, but explicit over implicit
        return None
```

Comment: Perhaps the deletion should not be done by the `get_new_owner` directly and it should instead call `CASCADE` so that no weird cycles or such occur?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: ah yes, indeed. In that case perhaps the `SET_WITH` should do that if the `get_new_owner`, returns `None`, since we need to have access to the collector, etc. and with the `SET_WITH`, we do not have such collector.